# Removing the url field from orchard comments

Tags: orchardcms

Looking to remove the Url field on a blog in orchard.comments modal. The problem is that the URL get linked to the username and i do not want my site linking to explicit sites or other content. I have tried display:none on the css but it would not take a genius just to display:block it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Placemente.info http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the content type and disable Allow custom patterns in the autoroute section.

Of you just dont want to display the field, download Designer Tools and use Shape Tracing to generate the view and then customize it as you need.